# How to create array out of object entries?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I need help creating a JavaScript object:

I have three fields from the input form in React state object:

```js
{
  calories: "45",
  fats: "56", 
  proteins: "67"
}
```

I would like to create a new array i.e. `nutrientInformation` from this data. The output should resemble this:

```js
nutrientInformation: [
  {
    calories: 45
  },
  {
    fats: 56
  },
  {
    proteins: 67
  }
]
```

Comment: Normally, these data points are put in an object like `{ calories: 45, fats: 56, proteins: 67 }`. The expected array looks cumbersome to use. Why is that your expected output? Anyway, what is your question?

Comment: If you want to ask a new questions, research first, make you attempts, then [ask](/questions/ask) a new one. Do not edit this question to fundamentally change its meaning, invalidating the existing answer and removing the formatting.

Comment: I am sorry I asked question here.I will research and solve problem on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const state = { calories: "45", fats: "56", proteins: "67" };

const nutrientInformation = Object.entries(state).map(([key, value]) => ({
  [key]: value
}));

console.log(nutrientInformation);
```